# R Regular Expression using "+" "?" or "*"

Tags: r, regex

From https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html

It describes controlling how many times a pattern shows up using:

- ?: 0 or 1.
- +: 1 or more.
- *: 0 or more.

So this works well:

```
str_view("hello123world", "123?")
```

However why not this?

```
str_view("cycyccyccccc", "ccc?")
```

The above highlights cc in the beginning of the string.

I was expecting it to highlight three c's in the last rows of c's at the end.

Comment: Multiple maching with a consuming pattern like yours will result in `[cc, ccc, cc]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regex you passed `"ccc?"` means (in words) "c followed by c followed by zero or one c's" so `str_view` gives you the first instance of two c's in a row (because that's c followed by c followed by zero c's).

If you'd like exactly 3 c's you could use

```
str_view("cycyccyccccc", "ccc")
```

Or if you'd like 3 or more c's you could use

```
str_view("cycyccyccccc", "c{3,}")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused why it's highlighting a pattern of 2 c's rather then 3?

Comment: Ah, okay - that's because you're searching for (in words) c followed by c followed by zero or more c's (what the ? symbol means).  I'll change the answer